# Store GIS Quadtree in Raw File (w/ Geohash) or PNG?

Tags: image-processing, data-structures, graphics, compression, gis

I am collecting GIS data consisting of normalized four values for whole world. I am curious on what would be the best way to store this data and wanted to take your advise. Would it be more efficient (in terms of size) to store the four values of the quadtree, along with a Geohash index via Z-order (Morton) or Hilbert curve? Or would it be more efficient to store it in a PNG file using alpha = 0 for empty spaces and lossless compression? The enclosed image [1](http://demo.htl.deals/France.png) only visualizes one of the four values over Google Maps and I need to store this global data each day. Please, note that I will only store leaf nodes as visualized in the image [1](http://demo.htl.deals/France.png) rather than the whole quadtree. I will also store this over time so I would also like to know your ideas about how video compression would improve.

Thank you all in advance for your time and consideration!